# Color detector program

Tags: windows, html, colors, pixels

I used to use the program [**Color Detector**](http://cosmin.com/colordetector).

> Simply run the program, point the mouse cursor anywhere on the screen, and the
>   color detector window will display the RGB values, HTML hex code, and the color
>   name of the color of the pixel pointed to by the mouse cursor.

However now the page is down

> Error 404: Page not found

I would like to download this program, or a similar program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[nielssp/colorgrab](https://github.com/nielssp/colorgrab) is an open source alternative hosted on GitHub.

It is written in C++ and works with Linux and Windows.

> [image: screenshots/main-win8]

Answer (score 0):

Their redirect script was broken. It has since been fixed. Alternatively, use
the direct link:

http://cosmin.com/colordetector/colordetector.exe

Answer (score 0):

I use a little tool called [Pixie](http://www.nattyware.com/pixie.php) for Windows.  Pixie does what you are looking for:

> Run it, simply point to a color and it will tell you the hex, RGB, HTML, CMYK and HSV values of that color. You can then use these values to reproduce the selected color in your favorite programs. [...]